Why would poulailler refer to galerie supérieure?
jlliagre quoted TLFi:

B.− THÉÂTRE, familier Galerie supérieure, très éloignée de la scène, où les places sont les moins chères.

Why would poulailler refer to galerie supérieure? I understand that paradis (old synonym of poulailler) refers to galerie supérieure due to its upper location, but I don't understand the choice of poulailler. E.g., is it because the audience in the poulailler tends to be noisier?

Poulailler, as part of the theatre vocabulary, comes from poulaille. The word poulaille used to be a derogatory word to designate people of low extraction1, it was used alongside volaille (created by analogy with valetaille2).
Until the 18th century the theatres were lit by chandeliers with candles and the wax from the candles would fall down onto the people underneath. That's why the parterre places were the cheapest (and they were standing places, no seats). When theatres began to be lit by petrol or gaz there was no longer the risk of being splashed by wax, and since the view onto the stage was better from the pit than from the upper galleries, sits were installed and the price of the parterre places became too expensive for the poulaille who then occupied the upstairs galeries, less confortable and with a lesser view. The name poulailler was given to the places occupied by the poulaille.
Here's the explanation we can find in the  Dictionnaire de la langue du théâtre by Agnès Pierron and given by the team Arts vivants from the  Guichet du Savoir :

Concernant le paradis, qui est « la plus haute et la plus reculée des galeries d’un théâtre », l’auteure s’interroge. « L’appellation vient-elle comme en écho des "mystères", ces représentations théâtralisées des Mystères de la religion chrétienne (Nativité, Passion, Résurrection) apparues en Europe au début du XIVe siècle ? Le théâtre était alors divisé en trois étages correspondant à l’enfer, à la terre, au paradis, de bas en haut. Ou bien est-elle une allusion au proverbe biblique "Les premiers seront les derniers", les plus pauvres qui prennent place au paradis des théâtres, retrouvant la première place dans l’estime des acteurs ? »
Toujours est-il « qu’à partir de 1830, dans les théâtres du boulevard du crime[3], on parle aussi de poulailler ou de poulaille. »
« Le poulailler, dernier balcon et plus mauvaise place d’un théâtre à l’italienne, tient vraisemblablement cette appellation imagée du fait qu’à la fin du XVIIIe siècle encore, le parterre debout, composé d’un public populaire qui recevait sur lui les coulures des bougies du lustre, fut relégué à ces places dans les hauteurs du théâtre. Ce public de « basse extraction », pour employer le vocabulaire d’époque, était appelé valetaille, basse-cour, volaille. »
« C'est l'architecte Nicolas Ledoux qui, le premier, en 1785, à Besançon, s'occupa de faire transiter les spectateurs du parterre vers le poulailler. »

This explanation is taken up by various leaflets given out by theatres, such as the Opéra-Théâtre de Strasbourg:

L’origine du nom « poulailler »
Les premiers théâtres à l’italienne étaient éclairés aux chandelles. Au-dessus du parterre se tenait un grand lustre qui en était garni. Le risque de coulures de cire empêchait d’installer des sièges en dessous. C’est debout que l’on assistait au spectacle, pour une somme modique. Les spectateurs plus argentés s’offraient des sièges dans les galeries, et certains d’un ton méprisant nommaient les spectateurs de l’orchestre « la poulaille ». Exit les risques de se faire ébouillanter par la cire chaude quand on équipa les théâtres de combustibles moins salissants : le pétrole, puis le gaz. On put donc équiper l’orchestre de fauteuils à bonne visibilité loués plus cher. C’est ainsi que « la poulaille » fut reléguée en dernière galerie, ce qui lui donna son nom.


1 Nowadays it is only used as slang for the police.
2 See this article in the Dictionnaire de l'Académie.
3 Boulevard du crime was the nickname given to the  Boulevard du Temple in the 19th century when the theatres newly built along the boulevard started showing melodramas that attracted crowds that came to watch the crimes and murders shown on stage. (Le Boulevard du crime on Histoires de Paris)

"C’est ainsi que « la poulaille » fut reléguée en dernière galerie", oui et en hauteur, comme les poules au point le plus haut poulaillier.

Ta réponse est bonne mais ce n'est pas la peine de critiquer les autres sans raison. Derrière tout ça, il y a quand même l'idée de poule en hauteur et le petit peuple en dernier rang en hauteur.

Likely a metaphor indeed. The term poulailler was certainly pejorative and can be found referring to that specific gallery in le Théâtre de la gaîté. It was recent a that time given the italics but was already mentioned in the Dictionnaire général et grammatical des dictionnaires français by Napoléon Landais (1834) with this définition: Populaire: les dernières places, et les plus élevées, dans un théâtre (Thanks @Gilles).
This excerpt from Guide dans les théâtres from 1855 depicts it that way:

Both the description and the drawing show some analogy between a chicken coop and this area.

The theater hooligans :)

The peanut gallery. No less derogatory than poulailler, if s/what less candidly so.

Poulailler était déja dans Landais 1834. Je me demande s'il y a un lien avec la pièce Poulailler de Benjamin Antier et Théodore Nézel (1827).

@Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Merci pour le commentaire. Poulailler a été créé au théâtre de la Gaîté. Il y a peut-être en effet un lien entre le nom du personnage éponyme et les places en question.

Les poules aiment bien se poser (percher) sur un endroit élevé dans leur poulailler.

Poulaillers: Pourquoi vos Poules Préfèrent Être en Hauteur?
[nos?] poules ne savent pas voler...mais elles adorent rester en
hauteur ! En effet, le saviez-vous : les poules préfèrent se placer
légèrement en hauteur dans leur habitat.

Pourquoi les poules préfèrent être en hauteur

Pourquoi en ont-elles besoin ? [des perchoirs]
Les poules, dans la nature dorment en hauteur  (instinct de survie). Depuis la nuit des temps, cette espèce s’est réfugiée dans
les arbres la nuit en hauteur afin de se protéger des prédateurs.

bon perchoir pour les poules

Dernier étage d'une salle de théâtre, au-dessus des loges et des
balcons. Il porte ce nom à cause du grillage qui empêchait les
spectateurs de lancer leur nourriture en réaction à la qualité du
spectacle ! Cette partie du théâtre est la moins chère du fait de
l'éloignement avec la scène.

Opéra national de Lorraine 

▪  Fig. et fam. Le plus haut étage d’un théâtre, d’un amphithéâtre et,
par métonymie, l’ensemble des spectateurs qui s’y trouvent. Les places du poulailler sont généralement les moins chères. Le poulailler
manifestait son mécontentement en jetant des pommes cuites sur la
scène. (On disait autrefois Paradis).

dictionnaire-academie
[[Il faut des mangeoires et des abreuvoirs, des perchoirs pour que les poules se posent, des pondoirs dans un endroit calme et sombre pour que les poules puissent pondre.]]
poulailler

Je ne vois pas ce qui laisse supposer une association entre poulailler et la hauteur. Les sens figurés plus anciens n'ont aucun lien avec la hauteur. Notamment « une mauvaise et vieille voiture », qui désigne déjà un espace où les gens s'entassent inconfortablement.

Le poulailler, lui, n'est pas en hauteur, il est dans la basse-cour. La basse-cour, ainsi nommée parce que c'était au départ la cour intérieure du château, au niveau du sol.

@Lambie As you fully undo my edit instead of at least keeping the typo correction, please note that poulailler has a single spelling since the 18th century. It's not poulaillier nor poulallier.

@None Ce sont les poules qui perchent en hauteur, indépendamment d'ou se trouve le poulailler. Au théâtre il est bien en hauteur. –

@Lambie Exactement, un perchoir se trouve en hauteur et si c'est cette position surélevée qui avait motivé le nom donné à l'emplacement en question, on l'aurait appelé le perchoir, pas le poulailler. C'est précisément le cas à l'Assemblée nationale.

@jlliagre Un perchoir n'est pas nécessairement "en hauteur". Je suis désolée d'avoir donnée une réponse bien en dessous de la hauteur exigée ici...

Ha ha ha :-).

@Kamala-1FTW Aimez-vous à ce point les oiseaux ?
